# Create public github repository with password to view files

Tags: github

Is it possible to create a public repository which can only be accessed through a password prompt. Anyone who visits your project page will know that a repository with a certain name exists, but they can only view the files in the repository by password prompt.

The aim is to allow people to access without creating and sharing SSH keys or making a private project, and without upgrading to a premium account.

Comment: AFAIK github doesn't support.

Comment: Zip your code with password.